# Directly copying values of evaluated Excel functions

Tags: vba, excel

I know that I can copy a column containing evaluated formulas, paste it into an adjacent column, and specify to paste values (i.e., a text string), so that the value sticks and I can then select, copy, and edit the value text as I desire.  However, I would like a more direct way to produce an editable column of values.

In order of preference, I would be satisfied if I could either:

(1) simply *copy* the values directly from the formula-containing cells by specifying a copy mode/option instead of having to specify a paste mode/option (so that if I want to paste the values outside Excel, for example, I can do so directly) - I believe this is not possible but would like to know if I have overlooked something

(2) write the formulas in a way that "throws" the evaulated values to other cells, overwriting whatever is in those other cells as needed, but passing no trace of the formula itself to the other cells

(3) use a worksheet macro that runs in the background and automatically copies values from column A into column B whenever column A values are updated or

(4) perform some operation on the formula column that removes the formulas but leaves the (editable) values (with the obvious drawback that you can't reuse the formulas once they are gone).

Which of these are possible?

Comment: Three and four are possible.

Comment: (3) seems impractical. Every change of column `A` would overwrite all edits made to `B` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *Event Macro*:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim r As Range

   Application.EnableEvents = False
      For Each r In Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlFormulas).Cells
         r.Offset(0, 1).Value = r.Value
      Next r
   Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

will monitor calculations in column **A**.  Whenever a calculation is made, all the values of the formulas in column **A** will be copied to column **B**

Note:

1. the data will not be copied
2. macros must be enabled
3. all the formula results will be copied, even un-changed results

Comment: Please note that as this answer stands the copying from column A to column B will occur every time the worksheet calculates. So if a formula is evaluated in column Z (or anywhere that has nothing to do with column A) this routine will copy the formula-produced values from column A to column B. This may or may not be a problem depending on the complexity of the sheet.

Comment: @ExcelHero  Good point!  another possible disadvantage is that cells may be repeatedly re-copied gratuitously, since I do not bother to see if the value has changed.

Comment: For some reason that took a really long time to execute.  It's not recalculating column A is it?  I have 40 columns in the spreadsheet and I am transferring values from column 39 (AM) to 40 (AN).

Comment: Also column 39 is the only column reaching across the internet - everything else is just concatenating strings within the sheet to generate hyperlinks and so forth.